# Mysql query killed automatically in python

Tags: python, mysql

I am using MobaExterm to run my python script. 
The script is fetching records from 3 tables. I can see the output of my query in MySQL Workbench but when the same query runs in my script, i get output as **"Killed"**

What is the reason. My query seems correct.

```
select tsp.data_ip, tsp.IP, tvp.vm_d_ip, tvp.IP FROM cmdb.t_server tsp,cmdb.t_vm tvp,t_ip ip where tvp.SERIALNUMBER= 'AD123' or tsp.SERIALNUMBER= 'AD123' and (ip.ip=tsp.d_ip or ip.ip=tsp.IP or ip.ip=tvp.dip or ip.ip=tvp.IP);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why this happens in python script is because of too many records.
The record exceeds the time to wait of the script while its running and kills it.

As seen in the select query, it is querying three tables at the same time with where clause mentioning multiple conditions in 'and', 'or'.

**Joins** should be used instead.